# Magento Command Line Global Commands

Tags: magento2, command-line

I am in a Digital Ocean Ubuntu droplet trying to toggle development mode in my Magento installation so that I can develop a theme.

My problem is I can't figure out how to run `magento deploy:mode:set developer`

I gather I have to make the `magento` command global.

Well I tried: `export PATH=/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/bin:$PATH`

and that did not work.

If I type `magento` into the terminal it says `Command Not Found`.

Please assist.

Comment: You can use `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` from the magento root directory.

Answer (score 7):

Another method would be to use `alias`

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

then add

```
alias magento="php bin/magento"
```

Log out and back in or run

```
 source ~/.bash_profile
```

You could change 'magento' to whatever you want (i.e 'm' or 'mage' etc)

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu try:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

add

```
export PATH="/path/to/magento/bin:$PATH"
```

Log out and back in or run

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the following issues:

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

> cd /site
>   php bin/magento

Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Someone help?

Comment: Your PHP version should be in 5.3, 5.4 or 7.0 / 7.1
Check!


What is the operating system
Cpanel, VPS, Linux, Windows???